# Suppose that $f$ has the property that $\{x \in E \mid f(x) > c \}$ is measurable for any $c \in \Bbb Q$. Is $f$ neccessarily measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f: E \to \Bbb R$ is defined on measurable set $E$ and has the property that $\{x \in E \mid f(x) > c \}$ is measurable for any $c \in \Bbb Q$. Is $f$ neccessarily measurable?

Let $(q_n)_n$ be a increasing sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n = a$, where $a \in \Bbb R$. Now $$\{x \in E \mid f(x) > a \} = \bigcup_{n} \{x \in E \mid f(x) > q_n\}$$ but the RHS is a countable union of measurable sets so $f$ is a measurable function.

Is the proof correct? I don't know if I should pick $(q_n)_n$ to be increasing or decreasing?

Comment: It should be "decreasing sequence". Increasing sequence does not work.

Comment: Of course the solution depends on the definition of "measurable function".  You seem to be using one of the common definitions, so this will be OK for your course.  However, note that the definition may be different in other textbooks. (But we hope the definitions are all equivalent to each other).  I am guessing $E$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$.  And I guess that means "Lebesgue measurable".  Such details should be included in a problem statement here.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan How so?